# Adding date and time variables and getting unix timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I foolishly thought you could just add the two and somehow magically get away with doing it the following way:

```
$time = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['time']));
$date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['date']))." ".$time;
$date = strtotime($date);
```

Obviously there is no way this would work. Basically, I have two fields, one where the user enters in the date and another for time. I need my timestamp to reflect both inputs. Any ideas on how this can be done?

EDIT: For example:
I input 09/04/2013 for the date and 7:25 for the time and got:
1378297500
which equals to Wed, 04 Sep 2013 12:25:00 GMT

Comment: [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: what you get when printing `$date`?

Comment: You need a space after $date.' '.$time too ... so that it looks like ... "2013-09-04 08:26"

Comment: print_r($date) and what your output?

Comment: @Akam $date gives me a unix timestamp, but it is incorrect.

Comment: @HappyApe I've tried that too, but the timestamp is incorrect.

Comment: what's your $_POST['date'] and $_POST['time'] look like?

Comment: @HappyApe $_POST['date'] would look like 09/04/2013 and $_POST['time'] looks like 16:00

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('CST6CDT');
$dt = strtotime('09/04/2013 7:25');
echo $dt . " - " . gmdate('r', $dt);
```

You will get:

```
1378279500 - Wed, 04 Sep 2013 12:25:00 +0000
```

If you're getting your date & time in `GMT` then set timezone accordingly before calling `strtotime` like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```